# Split row in multiple rows with R

Tags: r, split

I have a dataframe like this:

```
a <- c("a","b", "c", "d")
b <- c(7, 5, 4, 3)
c <- c("ABc","D", "EF", "BCEF")

m <- data.frame(a, b, c)
```

I want to subdivide each row into several rows, depending on how many letters are contained in the last column. So, I want a final dataset like this:

```
a1 <- c("a","a","a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d")
b1 <- c(7, 7, 7,5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3)
c1 <- c("A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "B", "C", "E", "F")

m1 <- data.frame(a1, b1, c1)
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows`

```
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(m ,c, sep = "(?<=.)(?=.)")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   a         b c    
   <chr> <dbl> <chr>
 1 a         7 A    
 2 a         7 B    
 3 a         7 c    
 4 b         5 D    
 5 c         4 E    
 6 c         4 F    
 7 d         3 B    
 8 d         3 C    
 9 d         3 E    
10 d         3 F
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
lst1 <- strsplit(m$c, "")
m1 <- transform(m[rep(seq_len(nrow(m)), lengths(lst1)),], c = unlist(lst1))
row.names(m1) <- NULL
```

-output

```
> m1
   a b c
1  a 7 A
2  a 7 B
3  a 7 c
4  b 5 D
5  c 4 E
6  c 4 F
7  d 3 B
8  d 3 C
9  d 3 E
10 d 3 F
```

Comment: I have this error: "Error: unexpected symbol in:
"separate_rows(m ,c, sep = "(?<=.)(?=.)""

Comment: I try to restart R session, but I have the same error

Comment: I have the same version of tidyr and my version of Rstudio is 1.4.1717

Comment: still doesn't working.. I don't understand

Comment: So? What I have to do?

Comment: These are normal operations that should have worked.  So, it is not clear

Comment: ok it works! I was on a project page

Comment: @Inuraghe  Probably, your project have an older version of tidyr?